# Ignoring "syntax errors" in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have an (ASP.Net) application that has the following client-side Javascript, to facilitate copying to clipboard:

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var is_ie = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua);

if (is_ie) {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputcopy"); // select it

    input.value = text;
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    this.focus();
}
else {     
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
        writeLog('Copy successful');
        if (showalert == true) alert('Copied to clipboard');
    }).catch(() => {
        writeLog('Copy failed');
        if (showalert == true) alert('Copy to clipboard failed');
    });           
}
```

We need to be compatible with all "modern" browsers - Chrome, Firefox and, don't shoot the messenger, IE11. The first two are fine, but the latter ...

As IE doesn't support the `navigator.clipboard` I've got the `if (is_ie)` in there, which works fine. However, IE doesn't know about the `Promise` in the non-IE section, and complains horribly about "Invalid Syntax" at

`navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {`

even though it'll never actually run it.

How can I tell IE to ignore that bit of code, or work around this issue? I've looked at conditionally loading a separate JS file based on browser, but that doesn't look like much fun. Is there a better option?

Comment: You can try `eval()` to get around this issue. Or if possible, just use a promise polyfill.

Comment: @AbanaClara — A promise polyfill won't add support for arrow functions.

Comment: @Quentin just convert it to normal functions. It's not like the entire block is 100 lines long

Comment: @AbanaClara: I'm sure it's not anyone's preferred solution, but `eval()` works beautifully! If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: `eval` does **not** work beautifully, it is slow, it is really hard to debug when things go wrong, and it can do confusing things with scope.

Comment: @Quentin: OK agreed - I did say it's not going to be anyone's preferred way of doing things - but this is for 5 lines for code. I certainly don't hope there will be any other IE-only requirements!

Comment: @KenD — Or you could just not use an arrow function in the first place (it isn't like you are even making use of `this` inside it).

Comment: @Quentin it is just a handful lines of code that doesn't look to be doing some risky stuff. OP isn't going to revolve around `eval()` like it was in the dark ages

Comment: @AbanaClara — I didn't mention "risky stuff" at all. `eval` is slow, hard to debug, and *much more complicated* than *just using a function expression*.

Comment: @Quentin and I'm not disagreeing with you. But this is just a negligible amount of code. This scenario is a perfectly acceptable compromise, if the polyfill and function expression isn't an option..

Comment: @AbanaClara — There is no need for a polyfill. Just the function expression. And there is no reason for a function expression to not be an option.

Comment: @Quentin ooh I get it. Since the code won't ever be executed anyway, the polyfill doesn't matter. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer by OP's suggestion.

You can try eval() to get around this issue. What `eval()` does is parse a string into an executable code. This will literally make IE ignore this code since it's not gonna execute anyway.

Yes, we don't typically use `eval()`, but rare scenarios like this are perfect reasons to use it.

Here's some resource about eval: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

<s>Or if possible, just use a promise polyfill.</s>

---

As @Quentin explained, merely using the function expression should easily fix this without using `eval()`.

Comment: "Or if possible, just use a promise polyfill." — The problem is the arrow function, not the promise. Heck, the promise isn't even being explicitly created by the OP's code (it is created by the `writeText` method, so a Promise polyfill won't do anything at all).

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I was doubtful that a promise polyfill is gonna work. But in case you're wrong, what if the `writeText()` method is actually still implicitly creating a promise internally via `new Promise()`? Perhaps

Comment: I'm not wrong. `writeText` **is** creating a promise internally, but `writeText` doesn't exist in IE, so it isn't trying to create one internally there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a JavaScript parser skip over syntax in parts of a program it isn't going to run (to oversimplify the situation horribly: It still needs to parse that bit of the program to find the `}` that ends the `else` block.

Either write your JS to use syntax that is supported by IE (i.e. use a function expression instead of an arrow function) or transpile your JS to a version that IE will support (with a tool like Babel).